# Unable to display field value in node template

Tags: views, theming, 8

If I devel the contents of my custom node--view--news.html.twig template, I get this array:

```
'body' => array(1)

  'x-default' => array(1)

    array(3)

        'value' => string(112) "<p>Curabitur ut augue at mi eleifend lobortis. Ut t asdfincidunt lacinia nisi ph…"

            <p>Curabitur ut augue at mi eleifend lobortis. Ut t asdfincidunt lacinia nisi pharetra. Quis lacinia dolor</p>

        'summary' => string(0) ""

        'format' => string(10) "basic_html"

'field_titel' => array(1)

  'x-default' => array(1)

    array(1)

        'value' => string(29) "Lorem / Ipsum / Dolor"
```

I can display the value of body by using

> {{ content.body }}

However using

> {{  content.field_titel }}

does not display the contents of the field_titel field. How would I display the value of a custom field in a node template?

Comment: Which template are you using this in?

Comment: Hello Matt, my template name here is 'node--view--news.html.twig'

Comment: It looks like you're doing it right. What happens when you do {{ content.field_titel.value}}?

Comment: Nothing .... kint(content.field_titel) is NULL, so there is no value.

Comment: thanks for help with downvoting without comments instead help to find a solution

Comment: The downvotes may be due to the lack of clarity and information in your question. I edited it to make it more clear. If you rename the template node--news.html.twig is it still unable to display the value? Side note: you might want to avoid sarcasm and rudeness in your comments, as they can be reported.  See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help for a guide on conduct and the best ways to get the most out of Drupal Answers.

Comment: See my answer. I think I know why it is not showing.

Comment: thank you Kevin, answered below your idea. Matt, thank you for your help too. So should the people write, that my question has a lack of information or is not formatted enough. Just downvoting dont helps. Sorry, if there was any kind of sarcasm in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same sort of question [I answered over here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/226067/57).

Check your node display settings to see that the field is not hidden for this applicable display mode (default, teaser, etc). It is not in the content renderable array because it is likely hidden in the display settings.

Comment: the fields i need are all visible Kevin. Thanks for helping me out.