# Why in node.tpl.php $content is different from $node?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I'm creating a custom template file for a specific content type.
I'm printing most of values with

```
<?php print render($content['field_blabla']); ?>
```

As some of them didn't show up and they are not empty I tried

```
dpm($content);
```

Indeed they aren't in the array printed, but if try

```
$node = node_load($node->nid, NULL, TRUE);
dpm($node->field_blabla['und'][0]['value']);
```

I can see the value!

What's the problem? Why are they missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like their field display settings are hidden, which is one reason it would not be in the `$content` renderable array.

Check the display settings for the applicable view mode for this content type on the "Manage Display" tab.

Comment: I have checked it, and it was ok for the default view, but not the "full content" tab...
So I checked now again and found the problem!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would be Default by default if full content is not checked off for custom display settings.